# Javascript method works and doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time even asking this question because I don't understand what is going on.

Basically, I have a spinning loader element that should be displayed while my javascript runs. At the end of the javascript the loader should be turned off and a modal should be displayed with data queried from a database. The problem is that the loader is never displayed. Theres about a 1 - 2 second wait while the queries run before the modal is created.

```
function includeConnectionJS() {
    if (!(typeof sforce === "object")) {
        var connectionJS = document.createElement('script');
        var documentHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

        connectionJS.src = '/soap/ajax/38.0/connection.js';
        connectionJS.setAttribute('onload', 'createLoader();createModal();');
        documentHead.appendChild(connectionJS);
    } else {
        createLoader();
        // Checks to see if the loader element exists. If it does not, create the element and than toggle it to display it.
        // If the element already exists, display the modal
        createModal();
        // Checks to see if the modal element exists, if it does not, create the element and than turn off the loader and display the modal.
        // If the element already exists, turn off the loader and display the modal
    }
}
```

I put console.logs in my methods and I can clearly see that the method is being called, the if statements are all passing and the visibility of the element is changing to the correct values at the correct times. Everything seems to imply that it should be working, but the element is never actually displayed.

I was able to get it to display by changing the call to createModal to look like the following:

```
setTimeout(function(){createModal()}, 100); // Most values for delay worked.
```

I don't want to create an artificial delay just to show loader for effect.

My primary concern is that the createModal method makes calls to the database. These cause delays in the javascript execution (I call them synchronously, not asynchronously). I can clearly see the loader display being set to 'block' before the queries, watch all the queries call out and return and see the display of the loader change back to 'none' all in the correct order. More than that, if I call the createLoader(); method directly from the console, it works.

I just can't figure out what it is I'm missing.

Comment: Everything you describe, from the order being correct to `setTimeout` "fixing" the issue sounds like `createModal()` is turning off the loader too soon. We cannot help you without seeing the rest of your code. A shot in the dark: if you want to tell JS to do A() after B has happened, you need to pass `function() { A(); }`, as opposed to `A();`.

Comment: @ChrisG No, it's nature of Javascript to block updates to the UI until the code being executed completes completely. Also javascript executes sequentially in a single-thread, so `A` will always execute after `B` for `B(); A();`. `A` is never able to start until `B` has finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With synchronous Javascript calls you are blocking the UI and other functions queued in the Event Loop https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Run-to-completion. It's important to remember that Javascript code executes in a single-thread. So no code can execute in parallel, everything else has to wait until the current task is done. In practice this means that you want your functions to do their job as quickly as possible so that other operations (UI updates, keyboard/mouse events etc., timeouts, or asynchronous callbacks etc.) can execute. They all have to wait until you pass back control to the engine through completing the current code block.

`setTimeout` works because it adds the long running `createModal` function to the Event Queue for execution sometime in the future (even when set to 0ms - it doesn't guarantee immediate execution it just says at first opportunity you can sometime after 0ms has elapsed. If you have a long running function that might actually be 10s later). Doing this allows the calling function to complete quickly and the UI is now able to apply any updates. Now when the javascript engine is ready to run further code it will look for the next block of code recorded in the Event Loop. This time when it runs `createModal` it will again block updates to the UI etc., handing mouse & keyboard events etc., but now the UI has had the opportunity to update, you'll have your spinner up.

So the choices are: either use asynchronous calls in your function so that it completes quickly, or if that's not possible continue using `setTimeout()` to queue the long running task after the UI has updated.